# Why does one label "break" and the other behaves?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

With the following HTML and CSS and jQuery (in jsFiddle), the "Begin Date" label breaks onto two lines:

Begin
Date

...whereas "Begin Time" stays on one line, as I would expect/want it to do.

HTML:

```
<tr>
            <td class="labelText">
                <label for="BeginTheBeguine">Begin Date:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="date" name="BeginTheBeguine" id="BeginTheBeguine" />
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td class="labelText">
                <label for="BeginTime">Begin Time:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="time" name="BeginTime" id="BeginTime" />
            </td>           
        </tr>
```

CSS:

```
.labelText { font-family: verdana }
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
var pickerOpts ] {
    appendText: "mm/dd/yy",
    defaultDate: "-1",
    showOtherMonths: true
};
$("#BeginTheBeguine").datepicker();
});
```

Why is "Begin Date" breaking, and how can I prevent it from doing that?

Comment: Just make the containing td a little wider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table isn't quite fitting, the browser needs to start *somewhere* and wrap text. Looks like it's picking the first cell.

If you want to force those labels to stay on single lines, regardless, try:

```
.labelText { 
  font-family: verdana; 
  white-space: nowrap; 
}
```